# Elequent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two Models,Product&Pdetail, all thing work good ,hasMany and belongsTo work too and I can check and create userdetail record via relations  in tinker but when I put my models in app\Models folder I can't get relationships between my models,I changed my name space in all {models}.php  to App\Models too.I checked in tinker too,can't get hasMany relations in tinker or controllers, for example in tinker

```
$product=App\Product::find (3);
$pdetail= new App\Pdetail;
$pdetail->body='some text about it';
$product->pdetail(s)->save($pdetail);    //(s)for hasOne or hasMany based on models
```

This works good 
But after changing location :

```
$product=App\models\Product::find (3);
$pdetail= new App\Models\Pdetail;
$pdetail->body='Some text about it';
$product->pdetail(s)->save($pdetail);
```

Returned 'bad method call',
I changed my name space in model files too(namespace App\Mpdels)
Can anyone help?
my product.php model:

```
    namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //
    public function pdetail ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Pdetail');
    }
```

and Pdetail.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pdetail extends Model
{
    //
    public function product ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTO('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

in tinker

> > > $product=App\Models\Product::first();
> > >           => App\Models\Product {#768
> > >                id: 1,
> > >                name: "HTC 10",
> > >                price: "11111",
> > >                avatar: "index1.jpg",
> > >                pcount: "7",
> > >                cat_id: 2,
> > >                created_at: "2018-01-19 20:14:54",
> > >                updated_at: "2018-01-19 20:14:54",
> > >              }
> > >       $pdetail=new App\Models\Pdetail;
> > >           => App\Models\Pdetail {#755}
> > >       $product->pdetail();
> > >           BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pdetail()'

Comment: show us your model??

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache etc?

Comment: In your second example you are using `&` instead of `$`.

Comment: @Marwelln with those eagle eyes, far too early for me hahaha

Comment: `Bad method call` can be about your routing... except what @Marwelln says about using of `&` instand of `$` ...

Comment: update your question with full model class please

Comment: Did you update your auth.php config as well? It has a reference to the User model.

Comment: Solved.i used dump command 3-4 times.and it worked.thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

thanks to **@Sohel0415** i tied this commands 3-4 times  and problem solved, don't know why in first use didn't work.

```
 composer dump-autoload
 cache:clear
 php artisan view:clear
 php artisan config:clear
```

thanks a lot